# Reflection to get field tag

Tags: go, reflection

In Go is there a good way to use reflection to get a field tag by just wrapping a field in a function from the reflect library?

I am basically trying to create a thin data access object that allows be to get the column name in the db without hard coding it all over the place.

Below is the struct with db column names as tags.

```
    // Table Structures
type CusipTableRow struct {
    Id          int64  `db:"id"`
    Cusip       string `db:"cusip"`
    Symbol      string `db:"symbol"`
    Active      int8   `db:"active"`
    Added_Time  int32  `db:"added_timestamp"`
    Description string `db:"description"`
    Exchange    string `db:"exchange"`
    AssetType   string `db:"asset_type"`
}
```

I am seeking a suggestion other than downloading another library on how to use reflection to essentially make a call like this to return a string with the tag value.

```
var row CusipTableRow
row.GetColumnName(row.Id) //Return column name based on tag.
```

I was considering possibly trying to use a map[address] fieldTag, but did not have luck getting that to work perhaps due to not fully having a grasp of the unsafe package. If that approach would have worked I was thinking a call like this could have worked:

```
row.GetColumnName(&row.Id) //Return column name based on tag.
```

Comment: You can't use reflection on a field, which is just a value of the field's type, to get information about the struct. Struct tags are a part of the struct's type information. You could have a function like `GetColumnName(&row, "Id")`, using the struct value and field name, but passing the field itself will never work the way you're describing.

Comment: @Adrian Yes I agree with you on I just can't use reflection on the field. My goal was to avoid having a hard coded string like "Id" floating around in the code. Is there a way to pass the address to the field and ref to the instance of the object to achieve this?

Comment: Theoretically you could, using `unsafe` and pointer arithmetic, but it would be extremely brittle and the potential errors would far outweigh the design preference to call the function this way rather than passing a field name. What is the context where you're trying to get the DB column name based on the struct field? Typically this arises in a situation where you're iterating through all the struct fields using reflection anyway (that's how most libraries using struct tags work), so this should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get field tag given the address of the struct and the address of the field.  Unsafe shenanigans are not required.

```
func GetColumnName(pstruct interface{}, pfield interface{}) string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(pstruct).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        if v.Field(i).Addr().Interface() == pfield {
            return v.Type().Field(i).Tag.Get("db")
        }
    }
    panic("field not in struct")
}
```

Example use:

```
var v CusipTableRow
fmt.Println(GetColumnName(&v, &v.Added_Time)) // prints added_timestamp
```

[Run it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XWtoI1Fapk6).

Comment: @I Love Reflection - Thanks for the code I am modding it slightly and going to integrate it into my data model for accessing a db. In your opinion, do you feel this a bad way to use reflection in go. Perhaps a better way to phrase it is there a better way to achieve this since go does not allow struct constants if I want to have some single place to map a field to a db column without just having a plethora of global constants.

Comment: I would write a tool that generates field name constants from the source like `const CusipTableRow_Added_Time = "added_timestamp"`.   Use the go/parser package to parse the source to an AST, iterate through the AST to find struct definitions and generate constants.  Use [go generate](https://go.dev/blog/generate) to invoke the tool.